# Proof that a degree 4 polynomial has at least two roots

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Let $$P(x) = x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$$
>   $$P(x_0) = 0$$
>   $$P'(x_0) \not= 0$$
>   with $x_0$ and each $a_i$ real. Prove that $P(x)$ has a at least two real roots.

I can't figure why this is true.

Comment: First show that if $(x-x_0)^2$ divides $P(x)$ then $P(x_0)=0$ and $P'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: I'm assuming $x_0$ and the $a_i$ are real?

Comment: @Taylor Yes they are

Comment: Hint: Show that there exists a point $x_1$ (near $x_0$) such that $P(x_1)<0$. Combine that with IVT and your observation of the limits at infinity on the same side of $x_0$ where $x_1$ lies.

Comment: You should draw a picture, one for $P'(x)>0$ and one for $P'(x)<0$. It will be easier to see the argument.

Comment: Since $\lim_\limits{x\to\pm \infty}P(x)=\infty$ there has to be at least one minimum and since you have at least one point $x_0$, where $P(x_0)=0$, either left or right of it, the minimum will lie. Therefore there has to be another point in the direction from $x_0$ to the minimum that crosses the $y$ axis. $P'(x_0)\neq 0$ excludes that the minimum touches the $y$-axis at a single point...

Comment: by 'has a least two roots', I'm do you mean 'has at least two distinct roots'? or 'has at least two real roots'?

Comment: @Ethan I thought of "two real roots"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that $P(x_0)=0$. Thus you can write $P(x)=(x-x_0)\cdot g(x)$ where $g$  is a polynom of odd degree. Thus, by mean value theorem, there is $r$ such that $g(r)=0$. If $x_0=r$ you can write $P(x)=(x-x_0)^2 \cdot h(x)$. But in this case you get $P'(x_0)=0$, so it is a contradiction and you get $r\neq x_0 $ and you get at least two real roots.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: have you tried sketching possible shapes for the polynomial, noting that the $x^4$ term dominates when $|x|$ is large.

> Hint: can you show that there is a value of $x$ for which the polynomial takes a negative value? Then use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

By the hyphotesis $x_0$ is a simple root of $P(x)$; $i.e.$ $(x-x_0)^2$ do not divided $P(x)$ because $P'(x)\neq0$. Then you can decompose $P(x)$ as follow
$$ P(x)=(x-x_0)(x^3+b_1x^2+b_2x+b_3)=(x-x_0)q(x).$$

Now $q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ with real coefficients; then there exists another real number $x_1$ such that $P(x_1)=0$; otherwise $P(x)$ needs to have $3$ complex roots; and this is not possible. Then $P(x)$ has al least two real different roots;
$$(x-x_0)(x-x_1)q'(x),$$ where $q'(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$. Now: if the discrimant $\Delta$ of $q'(x)$ is greater than $0$ you have four real roots (one of them could be equal to $x_1$), if $\Delta=0$ you have another two real roots $x_2=x_3$; if $\Delta<0$, $q'(x)$ has two conjugate complex roots; then $P(x)$ has only two real roots.

Notice that in general a polynomial with real coefficient of degree $4$ could not have real roots; for instance
$$P(x)=(x^2+1)(x^2+4);$$
so the roots $x_0,...x_3$ are complex and $x_0=\overline{x_1}$; $x_2=\overline{x_3}$; but if $P(x)$ has a real root; then it needs to has another one.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is simple. Since coefficient of $x^{4}$ is $1$ it is clear that $P(x) \to \infty$ when $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$. Now we are given that $x_{0}$ is a root of $P(x)$ and we need to show that there is at least one more root of $P(x)$. Since $P'(x_{0}) \neq 0$, it follows that there is a point $c$ near $x_{0}$ for which $P(c) < 0$ (if $P'(x_{0}) > 0$ then $c < x_{0}$ and if $P'(x_{0}) < 0$ then $c > x_{0}$, moreover there is an interval full of such points $c$ but we just need one such $c$).

If $c < x_{0}$ then we can see that $P(c) < 0$ and $P(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ and hence by intermediate value theorem there is a root of $P(x)$ in $(-\infty, c)$. If $c > x_{0}$ then we can show in similar manner that there is a root of $P(x)$ in $(c, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, assume by root, you mean real root here, and also assume all coefficients $a_i$ are real here.

No matter what, $P$ has 4 roots in $\mathbb{C}$, and since all $a_i$ are real, when $y$ is a root, $\bar{y}$ has to be a root too, where $\bar{y}$ is the conjugate of $y$. So $P$ can have 0,2,4 real roots, multiplicity counted. So only chance $P$ has a single real root is that this root's multiplicity larger than 1, in other words, $P(x)=(x-x_0)^2(x^2+bx+c)$. If this were true, $P'(x_0)=0$, which contradicts of what was given. So $P$ must have at least 2 real roots.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the given polynomial has the real coefficients. So we know that if it has a complex root then its conjugate must be the root of the polynomial. Now in the given polynomial since $ P(x_0)=0, x_0\in \mathbb{R} $ also $ P'(x_0)\neq 0 $ which implies the multiplicity of $x_0$ is 1; $i.e.$ if $P(x)=(x-x_0)g(x) \implies g(x_0)\neq 0.$ the degree of $g(x)$ is 3 which is odd. So, $ g(x)$ must have a real root as the coefficients of $g(x)$ is also real. Hence, $P(x)$ has at least 2 real roots.